# Different outputs in Valgrind across multiple machines

Tags: c, valgrind

In machine `A` for some reason I get a bunch of:

```
==21855== Invalid read of size 4
==21855==    at 0x422A26F: ??? (in /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.3.so)
==21855==    by 0x4216E2F: vsnprintf (in /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.3.so)
==21855==    by 0x41FE421: snprintf (in /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.3.so)
==21855==    by 0x804F95B: put_lines (lines.c:354)
==21855==    by 0x805076B: examine_lines (lines.c:658)
==21855==    by 0x80509D8: read_lines (lines.c:715)
==21855==    by 0x804EED0: main (app.c:564)
==21855==  Address 0x444230c is 12 bytes inside a block of size 13 alloc'd
==21855==    at 0x40255BC: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==21855==    by 0x804FF80: read_str (lines.c:464)
==21855==    by 0x80501A2: read_type (lines.c:522)
==21855==    by 0x8050663: examine_lines (lines.c:631)
==21855==    by 0x80509D8: read_lines (lines.c:715)
==21855==    by 0x804EED0: main (app.c:564)
==21855== 
==21855== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==21855==    at 0x422A27D: ??? (in /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.3.so)
==21855==    by 0x804F9A8: put_lines (lines.c:364)
==21855==    by 0x805076B: examine_lines (lines.c:658)
==21855==    by 0x80509D8: read_lines (lines.c:715)
==21855==    by 0x804EED0: main (app.c:564)
==21855==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==21855==    at 0x804F8F2: put_lines (lines.c:343)
```

Running the same valgrind command (even with `--leak-check=full`) in machine `B`, I don't get any errors

I'm using the same valgrind version **valgrind-3.8.1** in both machines.

Same behavior when I run other programs such as, htop (same version too).

`valgrind --log-file="logfile" --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes ./program`

Why does this happpen? and how I can I make valgrind be consistent across machines?

**Update**

code snippet:

```
void put_lines (char * name, char * date, char * month) {
    char main_str[2048]; 
    snprintf(main_str, sizeof (main_str), "%s-%s-%s", name, date, month);
    main_str[sizeof(main_str)-1] = 0;
    // more code
}
```

Comment: If it is not top-secret, can you please share a few portions of your code? put_lines may be a good start...

Comment: Have you looked at `2.5: Supressing errors` in the manual? What your system suppress file contains on both machines? What happens if you use an empty suppress file?

Comment: Also, are the two machines share the same architecture? Are you using the same exact binary executable file on both?

Comment: @n.m: Not the same binary file. the program was compiled on each machine. Using `-v` for suppressed errors does not output any of the conditional jumps or invalid reads.

Comment: @eyalm: I have posted part of `put_lines (lines.c:354)`

Comment: @n.m.: Machine `A` runs `2.6.32-5-686`, machine `B` runs `2.6.32-5-amd64`. I wonder if that could be the reason?

Comment: `main_str[sizeof(main_str)-1] = 0;` is (probably) pointless (`snprintf` already 0-terminates). These lines, however, are not the cause. What's `//more code`? The error is in that. Unless it has to do with the `name`, `date` and `month` arguments. It could be that `snprintf` reads them in chunks of four bytes, and thus read beyond the allocated memory, in which case the "invalid read" would be a false positive.

Comment: @DanielFischer: //more code is a bunch of calls to different functions. I'm trying to get another invalid read with less code on it.

Comment: @DanielFischer: My program makes use of `setlocale`. A quick example of `conditional jump` would be running the sample code from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/setlocale/) which outputs 2 conditional jumps in `setlocale`. Only on machine `A`

Comment: Well of course it could be the reason. Different architecture, different code generated. However it is impossible to say for sure without seeing the code.